# VLC - scale parameter does not work

Tags: vlc-media-player

I can't start vlc from the command line and tell it to play a video, for example, at 50% or 25% scale. Here is what I tried

```
vlc --no-video-title-show --qt-minimal-view --width=512 --height=512 --no-autoscale --scale=0.5 test.mp4
```

(Video in this case is 1024x1024 pixels). The window is resized to 512x512, but the video shows at original size, i.e. is cropped on all four sides. If I removed `--no-autoscale`, window becomes 1024x1024 regardless of width/height settings. VLC is

> VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)

Platform is Debian Stretch.

Comment: I used to use --scale regularly for years, until about 5 years ago when it stopped working, and it hasn't worked since.  Same behavior on Linux and Windows.